# One or two Passover lambs?

Tags: passover

Dr Arnold Fruchtenbaum said in his Feast of Passover lesson (mbs 114) that "*The lamb that was to be killed for the Passover was set aside on the tenth day of the month of Aviv or Nisan...On the fourteenth day, the lamb was killed for the Passover meal. **The next morning, another lamb** was used as the Passover sacrifice.*"

The following instructions for Passover are given in Exodus 12.

> <sup>5</sup> Your lamb shall be without blemish, a male of the first
> year: ye shall take it out from the sheep, or from the goats:
> <sup>6</sup> And ye shall keep it up until the fourteenth day of the
> same month: and the whole assembly of the congregation of Israel shall
> kill it in the evening. <sup>7</sup> And they shall take of the blood,
> and strike it on the two side posts and on the upper door post of the
> houses, wherein they shall eat it. <sup>8</sup> And they shall eat the
> flesh in that night, roast with fire, and unleavened bread; and with
> bitter herbs they shall eat it. (Exodus 12:5-8, KJV)

I am unable to find any passages that say two lambs are killed - one for the Passover meal and a second one for the temple the next morning.

Does each family kill two lambs?

Comment: Hi, can you further help me identify who Arnold Fruchtenbaum is and where he says this?

Comment: from Wikipedia, "Arnold Genekowitsch Fruchtenbaum (born September 26, 1943) is a Russian-born American theologian. He is a leading expert in Messianic Judaic theology and the founder and director of Ariel Ministries, an organization which prioritizes the evangelization of Jews" chas vesholom.

Comment: In the Temple on Passover, there were 7 sheep, one ram and two bulls offered every day (see Numbers 28:19) in addition (ibid. :24) to the two daily sheep offerings. Additionally, on the day after the initial holiday a single sheep was offered with the inaugural grain offering (see Leviticus 23:12). You decide if any of that matches what he wrote.